# Randomly Rotate text from a txt file in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to rotate text from a txt file

here is my below code but its not working, I don't know where I am getting thing wrong

```
 <?php
$text= file_get_contents("text.txt");

$arr = explode("\n", $text);

$max = count($arr);

$i = 0;
while($i < 3)
{
     $i++;
     echo $aText[rand(0, $arr)];
?>
```

In my `text.txt` file i have some text like

```
are
can
how
now
put
see
```

I want to out put it line by line but Its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: 1) where did you define `$aText` 2) `rand()` function take `min` and `max` parameters, you provide an array as the max value 3) your while loop doesn't have a closing curly bracket `}`

Comment: would `shuffle` not be a logical choice for this?

Comment: @catcon even after replacing `$aText` with `$text` and putting the `}` it is just out puting `aaa` thats all i see

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php


    $arr =   explode("\n", file_get_contents('text.txt'));


     foreach($arr as $key =>$value)
      {
        echo $value;//Prints the file content
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: your code output all the text in text.txt in one line

Comment: echo $value.'\n';